# PHP web crawler

Tags: performance, php, parsing, web-scraping

I'm working on a "nice" crawler that start with one URL, and find the other URLs to process each page, a kind of "Google" crawler, to index pages.

I worked hard on this crawler to respect many points I've found over many websites, including:

- Respect of robots.txt
- Not querying too much each website (I add a delay for each subsequent requests on the same domain)

The main code is a worker.php that is spawned using Supervisor. Supervisor launch *n* instances of that file depending on the server so it's possible that multiple instances of worker.php are running in parallel.

There is one issue I can't pinpoint: it seems that the more time it runs, the more time it takes to process the URL (it's getting slower and slower), and I can't target why and where (if you have any ideas, I'm interested!).

I've also created a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/cnicodeme/d3efb55112e0c776137fb8c9a06e4fd5) based on the code presented here.

```
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') exit(1);

require_once(__DIR__.'/../init.php');

define('WORKER_LIMIT_INSTANCES', 200);
define('CRAWLER_MAX_DEPTH', 10000);
define('CRAWLER_MAX_HIGH_URLS', 100);

use \Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;
use \Crawler\Models\LinkModel;

$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');

$reloadedInitialTime = filemtime(__DIR__.'/../reloaded');
fwrite(STDOUT, "Started new instance of script (".$reloadedInitialTime.").\n");

$loopCounter = 0;
while (true) {
    clearstatcache();

    // Script to stop the service
    if (intval(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../breakworker')) === 1 ) exit(1);

    // We check if we need to stop this worker (code update?)
    $autoReloadSystem = filemtime(__DIR__.'/../reloaded');
    if ($reloadedInitialTime !== $autoReloadSystem) {
        fwrite(STDOUT, "New update - Reloading script.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    usleep(500000); // Give it some slack ; 1/2 second

    $loopCounter++;
    if ($loopCounter > WORKER_LIMIT_INSTANCES) break; // We count on Supervisord to reload workers

    // grab the next job off the queue and reserve it
    $job = $pheanstalk->watch(QUEUE_NAME)
        ->ignore('default')
        ->reserve();

    // remove the job from the queue
    $pheanstalk->delete($job);

    $data = json_decode($job->getData(), true);
    if (is_null($data)) {
        fwrite(STDERR, "[FATAL] Invalid Job data : ".$job->getData()."\n");
    }

    if (!isset($data['retries']))  $data['retries'] = 0;
    if (!isset($data['priority'])) $data['priority'] = \Crawler\Engine\Spider::MEDIUM_PRIORITY;

    if ($data['priority'] == \Crawler\Engine\Spider::LOW_PRIORITY) {
        // Normally, only new links are in low priority
        $data['priority'] = \Crawler\Engine\Spider::MEDIUM_PRIORITY;
    }

    /*
     * The "Spider" goes to the website using a basic CURL request
     * It also pre-fetch the robots.txt the first request to ensure we respect it
     * With the following CURL rules :
     *  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE   => true,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT  => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 5,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 5,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => ''
     */
    $spider = new \Crawler\Engine\Spider($data['url']);
    $duration = $spider->exec();

    // First, we ensure that we are not black-listed
    // So we analyze the status code
    // For 401, 403 and 404, we retry once
    // For 408, 429 and 503, we retry 3 times, with increasing wait between requests

    if (in_array($spider->getStatusCode(), array(401, 403, 404, 408, 429, 503))) {
        $data['retries']++;
        if ((in_array($spider->getStatusCode(), array(401, 403, 404)) && $data['retries'] <= 1) // Only one retry
            ||
            (in_array($spider->getStatusCode(), array(408, 429, 503)) && $data['retries'] <= 3) // 3 retries
        ) {
            $pheanstalk->putInTube(QUEUE_NAME, json_encode($data), $data['priority'], $data['retries'] * 30);
            continue;
        }

        // We are here (and not in the "if" section) when the status code is in the array
        // but the retries are reached, that mean we stop for this url
        // So the next step will be to add it in the Link database and stop the data.
    }

    // We update the url in the database to indicate it has been crawled
    LinkModel::update($data['url'], true);
    if (strtolower($data['url']) !== strtolower($spider->getUrl())) {
        // We were redirected, so we add a new URL also marked as being crawled, with $data['url'] being the origin
        $jobId = LinkModel::add($spider->getUrl(), true, $data['url']);
        // We remove the job of the redirect url because we had it already in queue
        if (!is_null($jobId)) {
            // We catch exception in case the url has already been processed
            try {
                $job = $pheanstalk->peek($jobId);
                $pheanstalk->delete($job);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {}
        }
    }

    $domainName = $spider->getUrlParts(PHP_URL_HOST);
    $domainName = strtolower($domainName['host']);

    // Here's the code I do to index the webpages
    // I removed it because it's not interesting in our case
    // But in general, if you are looking for a similar work, you can implement your need here :)

    // This code extract all the links in the page to add them in the queue
    $links = \Crawler\Extractors\LinkExtractor::extract($spider);

    // And we add them now :
    $priority = $data['priority'];
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $parsedDomain = strtolower(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST));

        $jobsData = array(
            'url' => $link,
            'retries' => 0,
            'referer' => $spider->getUrl()
        );

        $jobsData['delay'] = ceil($duration * (rand(1, 10)/10000)); // Delay between 0.1 and 1 seconds x $duration of the request
        if ($jobsData['delay'] > 5) $jobsData['delay'] = 5;

        // We increase the time to wait per number of links for this specific domain
        $jobsData['delay'] = $jobsData['delay'] + LinkModel::countQueued($parsedDomain);

        if (\Crawler\Engine\Spider::HIGH_PRIORITY) {
            // Allow 5 simultaneous request on high priority
            $jobsData['delay'] = floor($jobsData['delay'] / 10);
        }

        $iCountCrawledUrls = LinkModel::countTotal($parsedDomain);
        if ($iCountCrawledUrls > CRAWLER_MAX_DEPTH) break; // We stop crawling this domain

        if ($domainName === $parsedDomain) {
            if ($priority === \Crawler\Engine\Spider::HIGH_PRIORITY && $iCountCrawledUrls > CRAWLER_MAX_HIGH_URLS) {
                $priority = \Crawler\Engine\Spider::MEDIUM_PRIORITY;
            }
            $jobsData['priority'] = $priority;
        } else {
            $jobsData['priority'] = \Crawler\Engine\Spider::LOW_PRIORITY;
        }

        $jobId = $pheanstalk->putInTube(QUEUE_NAME, json_encode($jobsData), $jobsData['priority'], $jobsData['delay']);

        // The add method checks if the url is already present in the database
        // To avoid adding multiple time the same url (and going in loop in case two sites links to each others !)
        LinkModel::add($link, false, null, $jobId);
    }
}
```

**The Spider:**

```
<?php
namespace Crawler\Engine;

class Spider {
    const MAX_DOWNLOAD_SIZE = 1024*1024*100; // in bytes, =100kb

    const LOW_PRIORITY = 1024; // = Default
    const MEDIUM_PRIORITY = 512;
    const HIGH_PRIORITY = 256;

    private $options = array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE   => true,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT  => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 5,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 5,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => ''
    );

    private $curl = null;

    private $url = null;
    private $urlParts = array();
    private $statusCode = null;
    private $source = null;

    public function __construct($url, $referer) {
        $this->options[CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION] = array($this, 'curl_handler_recv');
        $this->options[CURLOPT_REFERER] = $referer;

        $this->curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $this->options);

        $this->source = '';
    }

    public function curl_handler_recv($curl, $data) {
        $this->source .= $data;
        if (strlen($this->source) > self::MAX_DOWNLOAD_SIZE) return 0;
        return strlen($data);
    }

    public function exec() {
        $start = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        curl_exec($this->getCurl());

        $this->getUrl();
        $this->getStatusCode();

        curl_close($this->getCurl());
        return round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $start;
    }

    public function getCurl() {
        return $this->curl;
    }

    public function getSource() {
        return $this->source;
    }

    public function getUrl() {
        if (is_null($this->url)) {
            $this->url = curl_getinfo($this->getCurl(), CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
            $this->urlParts = parse_url($this->url);
        }

        return $this->url;
    }

    public function getUrlParts($key = null) {
        if (!is_null($key) && isset($this->urlParts[$key])) {
            return $this->urlParts[$key];
        }

        return $this->urlParts;
    }

    public function getStatusCode() {
        if (is_null($this->statusCode)) {
            $this->statusCode = curl_getinfo($this->getCurl(), CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        }

        return $this->statusCode;
    }
}
```

**The `LinkExtractor` class:**

```
<?php

namespace Crawler\Extractors;

class LinkExtractor {
    private static $excludes = array(
        '.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.svg', '.mp3', '.mp4', '.avi', '.mpeg', '.ps', '.swf', '.webm', '.ogg', '.pdf',
        '.3gp', '.apk', '.bmp', '.flac', '.gz', '.gzip', '.jpe', '.kml', '.kmz', '.m4a', '.mov', '.mpg', '.odp', '.oga', '.ogv', '.pps', '.pptx', '.qt', '.tar', '.tif', '.wav', '.wmv', '.zip',

        // Removed '.js', '.coffee', '.css', '.less', '.csv', '.xsl', '.xsd', '.xml', '.html', '.html', '.php', '.txt', '.atom', '.rss'

        // Implement later ?
        '.doc', '.docx', '.ods', '.odt', '.xls', '.xlsx',
    );

    private static $excludedDomains = array(
        '.google.', '.facebook.', '.bing.'
    );

    private static function _getBaseUrl($parsed_url) {
        $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '//';
        $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
        $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';

        return strtolower("$scheme$host$port");
    }

    public static function extract(\Crawler\Engine\Spider $spider) {
        $parsed = parse_url(strtolower($spider->getUrl()));
        if (!isset($parsed['scheme'])) {
            $parsed['scheme'] = 'http';
        }

        $base = self::_getBaseUrl($parsed);
        $host_length = strlen($parsed['host']);

        preg_match_all("/(href|src)=[\'\"]?([^\'\">]+)/i", $spider->getSource(), $out);
        $linkPattern = '/^(?:[;\/?:@&=+$,]|(?:[^\W_]|[-_.!~*\()\[\] ])|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))*$/';

        $urls = array();
        if (is_array($out) && isset($out[2])) {
            foreach ($out[2] as $key=>$url) {
                if (substr($url, 0, 2) === '#!') {
                    // see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started
                    $url = $base.$parsed['path'].'?_escaped_fragment_='.substr($url, 2);
                } else if (substr($url, 0, 2) === '//') { // generic scheme
                    $url = $parsed['scheme'].'://'.$url;
                } else if (substr($url, 0, 1) === '/') { // generic scheme
                    $url = $base.$url;
                } else if (substr($url, 0, 4) !== 'http') {
                    continue;
                }

                if (strlen($url) > 250) continue; // We ignore too long urls

                $urll = strtolower($url);

                $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
                if ($parsed_url === false) continue; // We ignore invalid urls
                if (preg_match($linkPattern, $urll) !== 1) continue;

                $isExcluded = false;
                foreach (self::$excludes as $exclude) {
                    if (substr($urll, strlen($exclude) * -1) === $exclude) {
                        $isExcluded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                foreach (self::$excludedDomains as $exclude) {
                    if (strpos($urll, $exclude) !== false) {
                        $isExcluded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ($isExcluded) continue; // We ignore some extensions
                if (\Crawler\Models\LinkModel::isPresent($url)) continue; // We don't add a link that is already present
                if (\Crawler\RobotsTxtParser::disallowed($url)) continue; // We respect robots.txt

                $urls[$url] = true;
            }
        }

        return array_keys($urls);
    }
}
```

**The `LinkModel`:**

```
<?php

namespace Crawler\Models;

class LinkModel {
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::get(), '_'.$name), $arguments);
    }

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function get() {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private $presentStmt = null;
    private $countQueuedStmt = null;
    private $countTotalStmt = null;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->presentStmt = \Crawler\Database::prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = :url AND `executed` > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) LIMIT 1;');
        $this->detailsStmt = \Crawler\Database::prepare('SELECT `job_id` AS `job` FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = :url AND `executed` > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) LIMIT 1;');
        $this->insertStmt = \Crawler\Database::prepare('INSERT INTO `urls` (`url`, `is_crawled`, `executed`, `source`, `job_id`) VALUES (:url, :crawled, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), :source, :job)');
        $this->updateStmt = \Crawler\Database::prepare('UPDATE `urls` SET `is_crawled` = :crawled WHERE `url` = :url AND `executed` > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) LIMIT 1;');

        $this->countQueuedStmt = \Crawler\Database::prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) AS `total` FROM `urls` WHERE (`url` LIKE :domaina OR url LIKE :domainb) AND `source` IS NULL AND `is_crawled` = 0 AND `executed` > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);');
        $this->countTotalStmt = \Crawler\Database::prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) AS `total` FROM `urls` WHERE (`url` LIKE :domaina OR url LIKE :domainb) AND `source` IS NULL AND `executed` > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);');
    }

    public function _isPresent($url) {
        $this->presentStmt->execute(array('url' => strtolower($url)));
        $result = $this->presentStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return is_array($result);
    }

    /**
     * crawled : The engine extracted this url
     * redirectedFrom : The url it cames from, was redirected
     *
     * In certain case, crawled != fetched. This means the $url was a redrection from an other url
     */
    public function _add($url, $crawled = false, $redirectedFrom = null, $jobId = null) {
        $url = strtolower($url);
        if (is_null($jobId)) {
            $this->detailsStmt->execute(array('url' => $url));
            $result = $this->detailsStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // We search if already exists
            if (is_array($result)) {
                $this->_update($url, $crawled);

                // And return the job id if present !
                return (empty($result['job']) ? null : $result['job']);
            }
        }

        // We insert
        $this->insertStmt->execute(array(
            'url' => $url,
            'crawled' => $crawled,
            'source' => $redirectedFrom,
            'job' => $jobId
        ));

        return null;
    }

    public function _update($url, $crawled = false) {
        $url = strtolower($url);

        $this->updateStmt->execute(array(
            'url' => $url,
            'crawled' => $crawled
        ));
    }

    public function _countQueued($domain) {
        $this->countQueuedStmt->execute(array(
            'domaina' => 'http://'.$domain.'%',
            'domainb' => 'https://'.$domain.'%',
        ));
        $result = $this->countQueuedStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!is_array($result)) return 0;

        return $result['total'];
    }

    public function _countTotal($domain) {
        $this->countTotalStmt->execute(array(
            'domaina' => 'http://'.$domain.'%',
            'domainb' => 'https://'.$domain.'%',
        ));
        $result = $this->countTotalStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!is_array($result)) return 0;

        return $result['total'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main PHP file seems to be doing a lot of work and a few of your functions are as well. I'd recommend [refactoring code](http://refactoring.com/catalog/). I see a few hard-coded values that could be better store in a configuration file such as JSON or INI for easy use with PHP.

As for why it slows down, you should use curl_multi, not just curl when using a crawler. curl_multi allows concurrent requests whereas running `curl_exec()` waits for the response. The more requests you make, the slower it will run.

The way I wrote scrapers for the wide6.com site was one process (download) download web documents while another (scraper) scraped the downloaded documents for video information then deleted the document(s). Do note in my example that I ran into a few problems. Filesystems limit the amount of files in one directory which I unsurprisingly hit. My approach to a solution was to create a sub-tree using the first character of an identifier as the directory name. The download process was basically a background process using curl_multi downloading up to 15 documents at a time per instance with a max of 10 instances. The site was on a dedicated server so there was no major impact on it.

The reason I took that approach is because downloads take time and processing/scraping documents using regular expressions or using the DOMDocument and DOMXPath class take time. But truly they are different processes with a simple relationship in which the scraper relies on the download but the download has no reason to wait for me to update the database or process the downloaded document. Its only reason for existence is to download something while the scraper had to wait on a document to be scraped. Keep in mind this was years ago and my approach would be much more elegant now.

I'd like to note that I do not think PHP is a great language for something like this. Perhaps take a bit time to learn a language with means of multithreading. Python is great, but I hate it due to its ugly syntax, but it's still easy to learn.

Either way, your code works and you are on your way to learning to develop beautiful code. My main takeaways would be to study object oriented analysis and design and refactoring, the former of which would make the later less necessary.